# How to edit the tooltip text in a highcharts boxplot

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the text of the popup on a box plot.

From the [api](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter) and the example linked there, I assumed it would be a case of adding a formatter function to the series.  So I went to the [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot) and clicked 'Edit in jsFiddle'. I then changed:

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
}
```

to

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>',
    formatter: function() { return 'some random string'; }
}
```

I expected the tooltip to change to 'some random string' (as happens in the demo linked from the tooltip api reference), but it was unchanged.  Any hints?

Answer (score 7):

The `formatter` should be added to the `tooltip` property of the main options object.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kxbXx/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look the refference.

**`series.tooltip`**
`"A configuration object for the tooltip rendering of each single series. Properties are inherited from tooltip, but only the following properties can be defined on a series level."`

[**Source**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.tooltip)

As you can see, there's no `formatter` there.

You're looking for [this one](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter), which have to be used in the main tooltip object.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ricardo mentioned if you add `formatter` property for whole chart's tooltip method it will apply the formatter for all the timeseries.

You can use `pointFormatter` property if you want to add formatting to individual series. Below is a sample formatter for a boxplot series.

```
tooltip: {
   pointFormatter: function() {
      const x = this.x;
      const currentData = this.series.data.find(data => data.x === x);
      const boxplotValues = currentData ? currentData.options : {};
      return `Max: ${boxplotValues.high}<br>
              Q3: ${boxplotValues.q3}<br>
              Median: ${boxplotValues.median}<br>
              Q1: ${boxplotValues.q1}<br>
              Low: ${boxplotValues.low}<br>`;
   }
}
```

Find the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a02coug4/)