# HighCharts add another series value into tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I have a boxplot with a scatter plot of the raw values drawn on top of it. I'd like to change the boxplot tooltip (when you mouse over) to display the total number of points in the scatter series.

```
       tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    headFormat: '{point.key}',
                    pointFormat: 'Median: {point.median}'
                 }
```

point and series are for the boxplot, is there a way to reference another series like series[1] and how would you get the total. Or can I reference an array with the total values.

Similar to [How to edit the tooltip text in a highcharts boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525831/how-to-edit-the-tooltip-text-in-a-highcharts-boxplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.series` contains a reference to the chart object, which in turn has a reference to the `chart.series` array.

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var arrayOfSeries = this.series.chart.series;
            console.log(arrayOfSeries); // doing something with all the series!
        }
    },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xaQJx/1/).

Answer (score 1):

According to [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter), you can reference to the series object via this.series. So for the total number of points in the series, you can try

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return this.series.data.length;
    }
},
```

It seems shared tooltip doesn't work on scatter, https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1431. So I don't know how to reference another series. Otherwise you can use this.points[i].series.